# Closed form of $\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{\min (\sin (x),\cos (x))}{\max \left(e^{\sin (x)},e^{\cos (x)}\right)} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Wolfram *Mathematica* says that the closed form of the integral is
$$ -\exp \left(-\cos \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)-\cos \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\right)\right) \left(2 \sinh \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \exp \left(\cos \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)+\cos \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\right)\right)+e^{\cos \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)}-e^{\cos \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\right)}\right) $$

However the judges say that the closed form is $\;-4 \sinh \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$

Are the judges wrong?

Comment: Judge is correct. The critical points are at $\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$ where $\sin$ and $\cos$ are equal.

Comment: In Mathematica,  `FullSimplify[Integrate[Min[Sin[x], Cos[x]]/Max[Exp[Sin[x]], Exp[Cos[x]]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]` gives precisely the answer of the judges.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand
$f(x)=\frac{\min (\sin x,\cos x)}{\max (e^{\sin x},e^{\cos x})}$ is explicitly
\begin{align}
f(x)&= \frac{\sin x}{e^{\cos x}}\>\>\>\>\>x\in (0,\frac\pi4), (\frac{5\pi}4,2\pi)\\
f(x)&= \frac{\cos x}{e^{\sin x}}\>\>\>\>\>x\in (\frac\pi4,\frac{5\pi}4)\\
\end{align}
and repeats itself over these two sets of domains. Thus
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)dx=2\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{5\pi}4}\frac{\cos x}{e^{\sin x}}dx=-4\sinh\frac1{\sqrt2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Entering it into Wolfram Alpha gives me that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\min\{\sin x,\cos x\}}{\max\{e^{\sin x},e^{\cos x}\}}\mathrm{d}x=e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}-e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}-2\sinh\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=-4\sinh\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

so the judges seem to be correct.

Comment: Why does mathematica give the long result in the question?

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Probably computation time limit.

Answer (score 0):

If $\tan\theta=1\pm\sqrt{2}$ then $\cos2\theta=\frac{1-\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}=\frac{\mp1}{\sqrt{2}}$, so *Mathematica*'s complicated expression simplifies to$$-\exp(0)\left(2\sinh\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\exp(0)+e^{1/\sqrt{2}}-e^{-1/\sqrt{2}}\right)=-4\sinh\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$As for why the software came up with such a complicated expression, that's a question for its programmers.